# Problema al insertar datos en Oracle 12c

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-12c

Tengo que insertar unos datos en una base de datos en oracle, pero no consigo hacerlo. La versión de Oracle que estoy usando es la 12c, y escrita en mysql, la sentencia es esta:

```
insert into libro values (
default, 
9788491291893, 
"TODA LA VERDAD DE MIS MENTIRAS",
"2019/02/21",
"Un road trip divertido, surrealista, donde todo puede suceder. Una aventura en carretera que habla de la verdad que se esconde detrás de todas las mentiras.",
@id_editorial_suma
);

@id_libro_todalaverdad := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Según he entendido en diversos foros en googe, hay una sentencia para esto:

```
INSERT INTO libro VALUES (default, 9788491291893, 'TODA LA VERDAD DE MIS MENTIRAS', '21-02-2019',
    'Un road trip divertido, surrealista, donde todo puede suceder. Una aventura en carretera que habla de la verdad que se esconde detrás de todas las mentiras.', 'id_editorial_suma') 
    RETURNING pk_id INTO libro(ID_EDITORIAL);
```

Pero no consigo hacer que funcione de ninguna forma, he visto ya varias páginas en inglés de StackOverflow, pero no lo consigo hacer. Esta son las tablas editorial y libro:

```
CREATE TABLE libro(
id  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
isbn VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
titulo VARCHAR2(50),
f_publicacion DATE NOT NULL,
resumen CLOB,
id_editorial NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT fk_libro_editorial FOREIGN KEY (id_editorial) REFERENCES editorial(id)
);

CREATE TABLE editorial(
id  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

En que estoy fallando? Gracias. Me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
    Error que empieza en la línea: 122 del comando -
INSERT INTO libro VALUES (default, 9788491291893, 'TODA LA VERDAD DE MIS MENTIRAS', '21-02-2019',
    'Un road trip divertido, surrealista, donde todo puede suceder. Una aventura en carretera que habla de la verdad que se esconde detrás de todas las mentiras.', 'id_editorial_suma') 
    RETURNING pk_id INTO libro(ID_EDITORIAL)
Error en la línea de comandos : 124 Columna : 16
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00904: "PK_ID": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Revisa esto: https://www.arungudelli.com/tutorial/oracle/auto-increment-identity-column-in-oracle-table-primary-key/

Comment: A parte de lo que te recomienda @Japv, el error en cuestión se debe a que no reconoce PK_ID como un campo válido, ya que el campo que quieres recuperar (entiendo que es el identificador de la tabla) se llama ID. Si cambias a RETURNING ID INTO... debería desaparecer este error en concreto.